# How do i measure the confidence with which the transliteration output works?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am using the Python code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-python-transliterate to transliterate my Hindi text to English. How do I determine the level of confidence of this transliteration output?

Answer (score 1):

Transliteration does not change the language, only the script. When you transliterate Hindi text to Latin, the text is still in Hindi, just written in Latin characters. The API maps words, phrases and individual characters.

If you are targeting an English translation, you will want to use the Translate function of the Translator API.

The API does not return a confidence rating in either case.